# Installation errors

Tags: system-installation

There are a lot of errors in the installation of the tool.

1. It can't mount the dev/loop0
   when made bootable with "sardu"
2. it auto-ejects the USB(unable to find and disconnect from OS)
   "while made bootable from YUMI, RUFUS
3. It stuck at

   `A start job is running for ubuntu Live CD installer (31sec/ no limit)`

**Note**:- I have checked the sha256 checksum. The Iso file is neither corrupted Nor modified.

I am running
Intel i3 2.67 GHZ
3GB RAM
USB 3.0 32 GB

Please let me know if you need more info
I like UI of this OS. Want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shuld try to re-download iso, because he say is corrupted(sha256 checksum is used to verify that iso is not corrupted).

If you are on Windows i recommend you to use rufus, i never had any problems.

Comment: Friend,
As I have tried the checksum, image is not corrupted.
I have tried making bootable CD using
1. YUMI
2. Sardu
3. Rufus.
None of them works.
I also tried VMware player to try that in virtual mode.
That too does not work. So it doesn't work for me at all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Making the bootable usb with rufus solved the problem for me.